# How to read only digits from a text file with fscanf in C

Tags: c

For part of my program i have to get info from a text file called "options.txt". This file is like that:

```
Team number 10
win point 2
draw point 1
lose point -1
```

I Wrote this code but it fill the options array with only zeros:

```
int options[4];
getOptions(){
    FILE *filePtr;
    if((filePtr=fopen("options.txt","r"))==NULL){
        puts("file could not be opened");
    } else {
        for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
            fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &options[i] );
        }
    const int teamNumber=ayarlar[0]; //first element of the array is teamNumber
    struct teams team[teamNumber]; // teamNumber necessary for teams
}
```

Comment: Do you need to retain the *negative* sign before `-1`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scanf("%*[^-0-9]");` to scan and discard all characters that are not digits or `-`.  So then you loop looks like:

```
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        fscanf(filePtr, "%*[-0-9]");
        if (fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &options[i] ) != 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "error reading file");
    }
```

Note that you should ALWAYS check the return value of scanf before using any of the resulting values, to ensure that they were successfully read and converted.

Comment: Or `if (fscanf(filePtr, "%*[^-0-9] %d", &options[i]) == 1)` all in one-shot? (but it is discarding the negative sign for the integer values)

Comment: The problem with doing it all in one shot is if there are no characters to discard (the next character in the input is a digit), the first conversion will fail so the second conversion (the `%d`) will never happen.

Comment: That subtlety should be noted n the answer.